# MS Excel: SUMIF where the criteria is a range of non continguous cells

Tags: excel, sum

I would like to add up every 8th column in row 7 (starting at M7), where the contents of the 8th column in row 2 (starting at M2) ALL equal the contents of cell I6.

Row 7 is numbers.
Row 2 and cell I6 are text.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks for reading.
Clara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single formula with a similar approach to that suggested by Dan, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(M7:IV7)-COLUMN(M7),8)=0)*(M2:IV2=I6),M7:IV7)`

Note the use of two `COLUMN` functions which will ensure that the formula still gives the same result if columns are inserted before the data.

I used column IV as the last column - (it's the last column in Excel 2003) - adjust as required

Of course this would be much easier to do if there was a common header value in **row 1** to identify the columns in question, e.g. if `M1`, `U1`, `AC1` etc. all contain **X**  then the total can be calculated using `SUMIFS` like this:

`=SUMIFS(7:7,1:1,"X",2:2,I6)`

Comment: Thank you barry houdini. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mod` to decide if it's an "8th" row or not, after that it's easy if you just create a bunch of helper rows

(move rows down as necessary)

1. in row X use the formula (dragged across all columns) `=(MOD(COLUMN(A1), 8) == 5)*1`  to get `1`s in 8th columns starting at column `M` (hence the `=5`). Note that the `*1` is to convert the `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0`. Also note this returns true for column `E` which you can manually ignore.
2. in the next row enter the formula `=A2=$I$6`
3. In the next row just add the previous two rows (you can really combine all three of these rows into on row with the formula `=(MOD(COLUMN(A1), 8) == 5) + (A2=$I$6)`
4. `SUMPRODUCT` this last row with row 7 in the cell that you desire this final sum to be